# How can I show only the prefecture that belongs to selected country?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'd like to implement automatic selections of prefectures depending on the country that user choose.
I mean, it shows California, New York, and etc in prefecture select if user choose U.S.

**Country** model has

- id
- name

**Prefecture** model has

- id
- country_id
- prefecture

Now I'm showing these field like this

```
<% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

 <label class="control-label"><%= profile_form.label :country_id %></label>
 <%= profile_form.collection_select("country_id", Country.find(:all), :id, :name_en) %>

 <label class="control-label"><%= profile_form.label :prefecture_id %></label>
 <%= profile_form.collection_select("prefecture_id", Prefecture.find(:all), :id, :name) %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change form like this

```
<%= f.label :country_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name_en, include_blank: true %>

<%= f.label :state_id, "State or Province" %><br />
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :prefecture_id, Country.all, :prefectures, :name_en, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

And paste in proper coffee file (if model is `profile` than `profile.js.coffee`) If it's in other model change profile in file name and inside file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().hide()
  prefectures = $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').html()
  $('#resource_name_user_profile_country_id').change ->
    country = $('#resource_name_user_profile_country_id :selected').text()
    escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(prefectures).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
    if options
      $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').html(options)
      $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').empty()
      $('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().hide()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:) I tried your codes, but this gives error back:( and I noticed that I was forgetting to put '_en' in my country select field. Could you please show me when it was 'name_en' instead of 'name' in country field??

Comment: please update your question with form beginning (`form_for` line) than I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. But I noticed the way you do here shows the combination of countries and prefectures all together in the same select field. Could you please make country and prefecture separated???

Comment: That was done for purpose. I've take idea from this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised But to see it you should subscribe (not free)

Comment: BTW what ids rails generate for your selects in HTML? resource_name_user_profile_country_id and resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id?

Comment: Updated answer. I'm not sure about ids used in coffeescript, so my snippets need some debugging.

Comment: Thanks I tried your code but it's still the same.  It even shows the country name in Prefecture selection field:(

Comment: try to run `$('#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().hide();` in browser console. And paste here output

Comment: ({length:0, prevObject:{context:({}), selector:"#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id"}, context:({}), selector:"#resource_name_user_profile_prefecture_id.parent()"})

Comment: it need more time for debugging. You can watch fre railscast on this topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus but it's for Rails 2. Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks!!. Are you going keep working on helping me? or giving up here?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. If possible, please help me out on this later:)